# How to keep Passenger from handling Shibboleth.sso URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, shibboleth

I have Apache + Passenger setup where Rails app is in the domain root.
The Application will be protected by **Shibboleth**, but asking for

```
/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata
```

Returns `404` error **from Rails**.

If I remove Rails app from the DocumentRoot (rename the folder), then Shibboleth correctly provides me the Metadata, but again stops as soon as I restore the Rails app.

How to keep Passenger from handling that URL? Should I make it an `alias` to some place? Where?

**EDIT:** I also tried this, but it had no effect:

```
<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
  SetHandler shib
</Location>
```

Comment: did you ever get shibboleth working with your rails app? any chance you can help me out. I am trying to set up something similar to this

Comment: @SurgePedroza yes, I did. The accepted answer should be what I ended up using, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better way would be disabling Passenger for /Shibboleth.sso in Apache

it should look like this:

```
    <Location /Shibboleth.sso>
            PassengerEnabled off
            Satisfy Any
    </Location>
```

Comment: Of course this is correct way. I actually found it somewhere else, but forgot about my question here. BTW, the `Satisfy any` part is not required.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache24 or higher. (apache + passenger + shibd). Also, make sure to load mod_shib before mod_passenger with LoadModule.

```
<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
  AuthType Shibboleth
  ShibRequestSetting requireSession false
  Require shibboleth
</Location>
```